# How dll.config file is used

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# project that outputs a dll: foo.dll. This foo.dll internally uses a legacy library legacy.dll. Here is how my library foo.dll will be used: first I upload these files: foo.dll, legacy.dll, and legacy.dll.config to a third party; then the third party starts up a process which loads my main library foo.dll and executes some functions. When foo.dll is being run, I see exception thrown in legacy.dll saying some configuration "baz" cannot be found. However, I can verify that the configuration "baz" is defined in the legacy.dll.config file. So I think the file legacy.dll.config is not loaded by the process.

So I wonder how config.dll files are used. In my case, considering foo.dll is the only thing within my control, is there a way to load the legacy.dll.config file?

Comment: They're not used. Only the configuration file from the executable gets used (in the case of a desktop app) or the web.config (in an ASP.NET app).

Comment: Just what mason said, only the entry point of the application has a config that is auto loaded. It is possible to load a config file for your custom assembly, but you need to code that loading by yourself.

Comment: @mason, thanks for the clarification. Followup question: if the dll.config files are not used, why are they generated in the first place when the legacy project is compiled?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to place the configuration section that your legacy.dll requires in the configuration (app.config or web.config) for the application that references it.

Do you have control over your legacy application - in other words, are you able to modify it? One occasional challenge is that when all of these extra values are dumped into the configuration it can be more difficult to tell where they are used. They can even get left in the configuration long after you stop using legacy.dll because no one knows what they are and they're afraid to remove them.

Going the other way, if the values are missing from the configuration, it's best not to throw a confusing `NullReferenceException` or configuration exception that requires someone to dig into the legacy code and figure out why it doesn't work.

#### There are a few things you can do to make this easier:

One is that **your legacy.dll can look for configuration values that are distinct and separate from the rest of your configuration.**

That could mean a separate configuration section like

```
<section name="stuffTheLegacyDllNeeds" type="Legacy.LegacySettingsConfiguration, Legacy" />

<stuffTheLegacyDllNeeds>
    ....
</stuffTheLegacyDllNeeds>
```

Or you can disambiguate the appSettings keys with some convention like

```
<add key="myLegacyLibrary:someSetting" value="true" />
```

You can also make it easier for other developers by throwing useful exception messages if a required key is missing, like "Legacy requires appSettings key 'xyz' which was not found." They still have to figure out where to find the values but at least they have a clear understanding of the problem.

Also, **if you find that Legacy.dll doesn't change settings often or ever, you can code it to replace missing values with default values.** That way they can override the defaults if they need to by adding configuration values. But if they don't need the defaults they can just not supply configuration values.

One more approach - this is the one I personally prefer:

**Make your legacy class depend on an interface for settings** like

```
public interface ISettings
{
    bool SomeSetting { get; }
    int SomeOtherSetting { get; }
}
```

and make your legacy class require an instance of `ISettings` in its constructor. Now the app that references it "knows" about the settings because it can't use the class without providing it. Your legacy library can provide an implementation like

```
public class ConfigurationSettings : ISettings
```

that reads from configuration, and the referencing app could choose to use it. Or it could supply another class that implements the interface. It could also provide a class that contains default values which the referencing app could change. It could also have a set of defaults that it uses internally if the referencing app doesn't provide any values.

Now,

- The referencing application knows that your class needs these settings.
- The referencing application can choose how to provide them.
- Your legacy library no longer depends on the configuration. It depends on an abstraction - `ISettings` - which can be implemented using configuration or some other way. That means your legacy library will be easier to unit test. Code that explicitly depends on configuration values is much harder to test, or likely never even gets tested.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the control over either the legacy application or the application project that generates the executable.